# data scraping for categories and products

Tags: product, category, data

I want to scrape a data from one of ecommerce website.

1. Where i want to pull all categories and products details.
2. What will be the best method to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are many data scrapping tools available in the market. Some of them are 
   http://webscraper.io/

https://www.import.io/

http://webdata-scraping.com/

http://www.habiledata.com/

For more information, google it. you can get more idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieved it by custom script to pull all the data from other eCommerce website/server, you have to access of third party database and server. The data formate must be compatible with native eCommerece platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common Python framework called [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org)

It's Easy to use, but need python knowledge.